# Select the last ten posts from database?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to only select the last ten posts from the database.
I had this code to select everything:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY PostID DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    ....
}
```

But when I tried to select the last 10 with this code:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM posts ORDER BY PostID DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    ....
}
```

...it doesn't work.

I get this error:
mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

What's up?

Comment: Filtering the number of responses is specified by `TOP #` (after the select) in sql server, but by `LIMIT #` (at the end) in mysql

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY PostID DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
```

Comment: `TOP 10` is a MS SQL Server syntax.